# Utility bar doesn't appear in Lightning App for certain users

Tags: visual-workflow, utility-bar

Simple use case:

- Lightning App `Foo` is configured with a Utility Bar.
- Utility Bar has a single item - a Screen Flow `MyFlow`
- Lightning App `Foo` is provisioned to Profile `System Administrator` and `MyCustomProfile`
- `MyFlow` is permissioned using the `Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles and permission sets` as shown below
- `MyCustomPermissionSet` grants permission to `MyFlow`; `Bob` is assigned to `MyCustomerPermissionSet`

> **Yet, when logged in as Bob, the Utility Bar does not appear in the Foo App. it
>   appears for the System Admin**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is ...

- If the only item in the Utility Bar is a Flow, and ...
- The running user is not a Flow User (in user record) or does not have `Manage Flows` or `Run Flows` permission (in either profile or Permission Set)

Then, *even if the specific flow in the Utility Bar has been granted to a Profile or Permission Set assigned to the running user*, the absence of the Flow User/Manage Flows/Run Flows will prevent the Utility Bar from even displaying (as empty or with the flow).

In my use case, I needed to add the `Run Flows` permission to the Permission Set that granted access to the flow - thus encapsulating all the required permissions for the flow in one place.